# Facebook Business SDK for Python does not return video_play_curve_actions field for AdAccount insights

Tags: facebook-business-sdk

#### The problem

[Facebook Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/) does not return the field `video_play_curve_actions` when using the their [Python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk). More specifically the Async report download method.

The same field can be observed to be returned when using their REST API.

#### What has been tried

I have created a POC [here](https://gist.github.com/riju-dc/92b7556f92b5fda1f1d62da028197e81).

This has two functions. One of them uses the [Python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk). The other one uses Facebook's REST API: [Facebook Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/).

I was expecting to see the field `video_play_curve_actions` being returned in both the functions. Only the REST API returns this field.